# youtube api cannot upload to a channel of mine

Tags: .net-core, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using C# (.net 7) and google api package to upload but cannot upload it to a specific channel. It seems it ignores `video.Snippet.ChannelId`

```
video.Snippet.ChannelId = "UCXXXXXXXXXX";
```

whenever I try to upload this way it upload to personal account (default youtube channel)

I also tried to use `OnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel` and `OnBehalfOfContentOwner`

```
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");

            videosInsertRequest.OnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel = "UCXXXXXXXXXX";
            videosInsertRequest.OnBehalfOfContentOwner = "{ChannelHandler*}";
```

I am getting the below error;

```
An error prevented the upload from completing.
The service youtube has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account. [403]
Errors [
    Message[The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.] Location[ - ] Reason[accountDelegationForbidden] Domain[youtube.common]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service youtube has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.InitiateSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.UploadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something but not sure what. I have similar issues to download my own caption but I am assuming this will also fix that issue as well.

*Channel handler is what you see in the channel page with @ eg for https://www.youtube.com/@VOLEapp I assume it is VOLEapp

Thanks,